# how to create menu using a sprite sheet in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I just started learning cocos2d-x.

I am trying to create menu using sprite sheet, below:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()>addSpriteFramesWithFile("my_menu.plist");

 CCMenuItem *play = CCMenuItemImage::create("play.png", NULL,NULL,this , menu_selector(StartScene::clickStart));

CCMenu *pMenu = CCMenu::create(play,NULL);

addChild(pMenu);
```

I got error message:

get data from file (play.png) failed.

I realise something wrong with my create function. I am just wondering how to get the image from sharedSpriteFrameCache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I just figure it out:

```
 CCMenuItemSprite *play = CCMenuItemSprite::create(CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("play.png"), NULL,NULL,this ,menu_selector(StartScene::clickStart));
```

`spriteWithSpriteFrameName` is deprecated, instead, we can use:

`CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName()`;

Answer (score -1):

u need to take the plist file in a ccspritebatchnode object and manipulate it using this object.

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"AnimBear.png"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet];
```